# Compare comma separated value in comma separated column in sql server with different sequence

Tags: sql-server

I have column in my table that contains the values like that:

> 1,3,4,2,6,5

I want to check all the values in the above column..

how to do it??

I want to run the query like ths:

```
select * from table where column contains 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I tried to use like operator but it does not work if column has without sequence values..

Comment: how to sort column values

Comment: You should fix your data model and stop storing comma delimited values.

Comment: it has varchar type values

Comment: user2003615 - please demonstrate some respect. People here are doing you a favour.

Comment: Is that a swear word?I can see the answers coming...

Comment: sorry  raj  it's frustrating me.. plz guys  help me..

Comment: It means - "Use your brain to just answer the question asked. There is no need to be overly smart". I apologize on his behalf.

Comment: I apologize on my behalf guys..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744391/t-sql-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-of-numbers-to-integer

Answer (score 0):

That's not very efficient, but will do:

```
select 
    * 
from [table]
where ','+ '1,2,3,4,5,6' +',' like '%,'+ cast(column as varchar(255)) +',%'
```