# SQL - Convert String of numbers to list of integers

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

am passing in a string of numbers and would like to convert this string into a list of numbers e.g.

```
SELECT personID from person WHERE personID IN ('927,6944')
```

How do I convert ('927,6944') to (927,6944)

This is the error message I get when I try and run the query:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '927,6944' to data type int.

Comment: where are you generating '927,6944' from ?

Comment: From the error message, it's obviously MS SQL Server.

Comment: This answer may also be usable for your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744391/t-sql-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-of-numbers-to-integer

Comment: I am passing '927,6944' as a string value that is generated via java code.  This value will typically be different and can contain a larger String of numbers.  Yes, this is a SQL message that I get when I run the query on SQL server.

Comment: If you are passing the string to a stored procedure parameter then take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334380/how-to-split-explode-comma-delimited-string-field-into-sql-query/19335966#19335966

Comment: @podiluska, you have used your gold powers poorly.  This is not about splitting a string.  Please fully read and understand a question before exercising your new powers.  You must be 8 times more certain that its a dupe.

Comment: @paqogomez I am 20x certain it's a dupe.

Comment: I was able to use the post above that bsivel provided to create a temp table that converts the values passed into the stored procedure then join on the temp table.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @podiluska And now the [real answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334380/how-to-split-explode-comma-delimited-string-field-into-sql-query/19335966#19335966) (that _would_ be a dupe of this) is marked as a dupe.. by you.   Great way to prove your point i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes (quotes imply varchar)

```
SELECT personID FROM person WHERE personID IN (927, 6944)
```

Comment: Also, replaceing `, ` with `', '` would fix the quote issue to give you `IN ('972','6944')`.  The conversion would happen properly.

Comment: OP says that he is **passing the values from the program**.

Comment: USING QUOTES ON INTEGERS!!! KILL IT WITH FIRE!!!

Comment: Wish it were that easy, but I'm passing this value in as a string.  The amount of numbers in the string can vary. i.e. it won't always be '927, 6944'.

Comment: You're passing in the quotes too? Remove them or (god help us all) do what paqogomez suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic sql. Pass the value '927,6944' as `@Parameter`

```
DECLARE @Parameter varchar(100)
DECLARE @Query varchar(200)
SET @Parameter='927,6944'   --An example

SET @Query='SELECT personID from person WHERE personID IN ('+@Parameter+')'
EXEC(@Query);
```

**Explanation:**

While executing, `@Query` contains the following:

```
SELECT personID FROM person WHERE personID IN (927, 6944)
```

**OR**

You need to make the whole query from the program itself and execute it directly.

Comment: This is bad practice and potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is possible to generate this query from your java code without the quote marks. The string with these numbers in it need not contain quote marks when being injected into the SQL. If for some reason the quote makes are not easy to remove when making the query, try passing it through a string replace method in your java code that will strip out the quote marks.